# Sphinx documentation of django tests

Tags: django, python-sphinx

I'm using Sphinx for my django project documentation. I want to document all my tests.
How can I tell index.rst to bring all the autodoc strings from all the files that start with "test..." from my project directory.
I don't want to write:

```
.. automodule:: my_project.some_app.tests.test_api

.. autoclass:: my_project.some_app.tests.test_api.TestAPI
    :members:
```

for each test file that I have in the project.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: did you figure out this problem? After 10 years I have same case:)

Comment: @dannydedog Nope. Didn’t touch it for 10 years :)